# How give each element in a vector it's order

Tags: matlab, performance, vectorization

For example, I have the sorted vector:
[9 9 9 10 13 13 14 15 ]
and I want to give each element it's order (and keep identical elements).
i.e. I want the answer to be:
[1 1 1 2 3 3 4 5]

Any ideas?
Thanks!

*Note:* my real vector is much larger (about 50,000 elements) so I cannot do it manually...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the sorted nature of input data, here's an approach with [`cumsum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) and [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) -

```
cumsum([logical(1) diff(a)~=0])
```

Runtime test -

```
>> a = sort(randi([10,10000],[1,10000000]));% Input array
>> tic,[~,~,idx] = unique(a);toc  % @rahnema1's soln with unique
Elapsed time is 0.883363 seconds.
>> tic,cumsum([logical(1) diff(a)~=0]);toc
Elapsed time is 0.074566 seconds.
```

Comment: Is `logical(1)` any faster than `true`?

Comment: @LuisMendo Was a shameful moment, as I just forgot how to get boolean `1` in MATLAB. In Numpy we have `True` and that didn't work here, so I just went with `logical`. Eventually I figured it out, but didn't wanna make an edit for that small thing. Too much of NumPy isn't helping ;)

Comment: @Divakar Haha. That's exactly what I fear if I learn Python/Numpy

Answer (score 3):

You can use `unique` function

```
a=[9 9 9 10 13 13 14 15 ] 
[~,~,idx] = unique(a)
```